# chrome won't load swf files

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, flash

I was asked by a family member to fix their site, but since I don't work in Flash I'm not certain how to target the problem.

The site is in Wordpress 3.2.1 and uses two small .swf files created in CS5 - neither of which will load in Chrome 11 or 13. They test ok in Firefox/Safari/IE for all modern versions. I've been digging for an answer but it seems this problem may be both pervasive and unique to each local environment. Maybe someone here has a fix?

here is the site: www.countdowntoday.com

here is the code from the index page:

`<object width="400" height="320">
    <param name="movie" value="countdown.swf">
    <embed src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/flash/countdown.swf" width="400" height="320">
    </embed>
    </object>`

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that `value="countdown.swf"` and `src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/flash/countdown.swf"` points to differents places.

Change the `value` property to the same as `src` and should work.

Also, please check this guide in order to embed correctly flash files http://latrine.dgx.cz/how-to-correctly-insert-a-flash-into-xhtml

Comment: Thanks sanbor - strange that I couldn't find such a succinct answer anywhere else, but I really appreciate your time. I followed the instructions in the guide you referenced and everything seems to work properly now.